# Modifying a complex fixed text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file like this example:

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
10.000000
```

each text line(starting with fit) is followed by some number lines. I want to sum all numbers which are below each text line (so they are in the same group) and replace the last number of that group by the sum of number of that specific group and also replace the rest of numbers by 1.000000 - like in this output example:

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
12.000000
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
5.000000
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
50.000000
```

and write it into a new file.

I tried this code in Python, but actually did not return what I want.

```
infile = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in infile:
    if line startswith"fit":
        for l in len(line):
            line[l] = line + line[l+1]
```

Do you know how to do that in python?

Comment: Do you also want to change '10' to '1'?

Comment: line.startswith("fit")

Comment: yes. like the example output

Comment: More than just the last number have been changed in the example output. Please [edit] your question and fix it or do a better job explaining the goal.

Answer (score 2):

```
lines = open("file.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
_sum = 0.
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
  if not line.startswith('fit') :
    _sum += float(line) 
    lines[i] = '{:0.6f}'.format(1.)

  if line.startswith('fit') and  i > 0:
    lines[i-1] = '{:0.6f}'.format(_sum)
    _sum = 0
  elif i+1 >= len(lines):
    lines[i] = '{:0.6f}'.format(_sum)


print '\n'.join(lines)
```

output

```
fit c3 start=1455035 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
12.000000
fit c2 start=5195348 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
5.000000
fit c4 start=6587009 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
50.000000
```

Comment: Your output is incorrect. It does not sum last row of digit group

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this out.

```
prev_string = ' '
global_string = ''
temp_sum = 0

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    prev_string = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if prev_string[0] == 'f':
            global_string += prev_string
        elif (line[0].isdigit() and prev_string[0].isdigit()):
            global_string += '1.000000\n'
            temp_sum += float(prev_string[:-1])
        else:
            temp_sum += float(prev_string[:-1])
            global_string += str(format(temp_sum, '.6f')) + '\n'
            temp_sum = 0
        prev_string = line
    global_string += str(format(temp_sum + float(prev_string[:-1]), '.6f'))

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(global_string)
```